# Shopify doesn't hide unavailable variant

Tags: filter, shopify, liquid, variant

I'm having trouble hiding a sold out variant in the search filter result.
[image: screenshot for clarity]

Like in this picture, that is the result from clicking size-42 in the drop down. Now the issue is, that first item "eleven" is not available in size 42. It is, although, available in another size. So it shouldn't appear here.
Here's my select code that populates my dropdown

```
     <select class="filters-toolbar__input hidden" name="FilterTags" id="FilterTags" aria-describedby="a11y-refresh-page-message a11y-selection-message">
        {% if current_tags %}
          {% if collection.handle %}
            <option value="/collections/{{ collection.handle }}">{{ 'collections.filters.all_tags' | t }}</option>
          {% elsif collection.current_type %}
            <option value="{{ collection.current_type | url_for_type }}">{{ 'collections.filters.all_tags' | t }}</option>
          {% elsif collection.current_vendor %}
            <option value="{{ collection.current_vendor | url_for_vendor }}">{{ 'collections.filters.all_tags' | t }}</option>
          {% endif %}
        {% else %}
          <option value="">{{ 'collections.filters.all_tags' | t }}</option>
        {% endif %}
        {% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
          <option value="/collections/{% if collection.handle != blank %}{{ collection.handle }}{% else %}all{% endif %}/{{ tag | handleize }}"{% if current_tags contains tag %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ tag }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
```

Any help please?

Comment: What's the URL of the page you're on (starting with `/collections/`, if you don't want to share the entire link)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the where filter to remove unavailable products or variants: https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/filters#where